# Simple cc_library rule as a Skylark rule

Tags: bazel

I have a very simple `cc_library()` rule that I would like to convert to a Skylark rule.

The `cc_library()` rule is:

```
cc_library(
  name = 'cc_library_a',
  srcs = [ 'a.c' ],
)
```

The challange I'm facing is concerining compilation flags that get passed through different methods - for one, the command line.
So assume I run the following command line:

`# bazel build :a --copt -H`

This will add the `-H` flag to the compilation command. The question here is how can I get the `-H` flag propagated to a Skylark rule?

I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
def _my_rule(ctx):
    _arguments = [ '-c' ]
    _arguments.append(ctx.file.src.path)
    _arguments += ctx.fragments.cpp.c_options
    _arguments += [ '-o', ctx.outputs.out.path ]

    ctx.actions.run(
        outputs = [ ctx.outputs.out ],
        inputs = [ ctx.file.src ],
        arguments = _arguments,
        executable = ctx.fragments.cpp.compiler_executable,
    )

my_rule = rule(
    implementation = _my_rule,
    attrs = {
        'src': attr.label(allow_single_file = True),
    },
    outputs = {
        'out': '%{name}.o',
    },
    fragments = [ 'cpp' ],
)
```

The **BUILD** file content is the following:

```
load(':rules.bzl', 'my_rule')

my_rule(
    name = 'skylark_a',
    src = 'a.c',
)


cc_library(
    name = 'cc_library_a',
    srcs = [ 'a.c' ],
)
```

The output of building the Skylark rule shows clearly that the `--copt` was ignored:

```
# bazel build skylark_a --copt -H --subcommands
INFO: Found 1 target...
>>>>> # //:skylark_a [action 'SkylarkAction skylark_a.o']
(cd /bazel/jbasila/_bazel_jbasila/4d692aace2e7e1a45eec9fac3922ea8d/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
  /usr/bin/gcc -c a.c -o bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/skylark_a.o)
INFO: From SkylarkAction skylark_a.o:
a.c: In function 'a':
a.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'puts' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     puts("a");
     ^~~~
Target //:skylark_a up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/skylark_a.o
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.578s, Critical Path: 0.05s
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If this is supposed to be about the C++ code, please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] of that code. Otherwise, just remove the C++ tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `--copt -H` parameter is generic to C and C++ you need to get the flags using `ctx.fragments.cpp.compiler_options([])` instead. The `ctx.fragments.cpp.c_options` code you where using is just for C specific options.

Likewise, there is also a `ctx.fragments.cpp.cxx_options([])` function that provides you C++ specific options.